# Force https for a single domain (complex implementation)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a website running on a dedicated server (single IP) on apache. **Multiple domains are pointed to the website** . For ex: sub.abc.com, sub.bcdaf.com

I have now purchased a single SSL certificate for one of the domains (sub.abc.com). Only SSL only works when user accesses https://sub.abc.com

I want to force users to https when they access http. And by default, when they access sub.abc.com, it should go to https://sub.abc.com . How can i do this via htaccess?

**Please note that the https should work only for sub.abc.com and should forceing users should happen only for sub.abc.com**

I'm have observed that using mod_rewrite in .htaccess is impacting performance of the site.
Pleas suggest the best way.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your .htaccess should work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but something would redirect to https for all the domains right?

Comment: Please note that the https should work only for sub.abc.com and should forceing users should happen only for sub.abc.com